# Find the infinite product

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

> Find the infinite product $$\left(\dfrac{2}{1}\cdot\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4}{5}\cdot\dfrac{6}{5}\cdot\dfrac{6}{7}\cdot\dfrac{8}{7}\cdots\right)$$

I solved it, but my method is not nice one. I solved it using calculus (that's why tagged). Please give a nice and sweet solution.

#### Answer

> $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @anomaly I need a nice and sweet solution

Comment: Why have the factor $\pi$ in there?  Also please use \cdot for multiplication instead of periods.  Periods can look like decimal points in many uses.

Comment: Try using $\log$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the product as a limit of a ratio of gamma functions as follows
$$
\eqalign{
  & P = {2 \over 1}{2 \over 3}{4 \over 3}{4 \over 5}{6 \over 5}{6 \over 7} \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {{{2n} \over {2n - 1}}{{2n} \over {2n + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {{n \over {n - 1/2}}{n \over {n + 1/2}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{1 + k} \over {1/2 + k}}{{1 + k} \over {3/2 + k}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty } \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {{{1 + k} \over {1/2 + k}}{{1 + k} \over {3/2 + k}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty } {{1^{\,\overline {\,m} } } \over {\left( {1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m} } }}
 {{1^{\,\overline {\,m} } } \over {\left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty } {{{{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( 1 \right)}}}
 \over {{{\Gamma \left( {1/2 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}}}{{{{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( 1 \right)}}} \over {{{\Gamma \left( {3/2 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)}}}} =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty } {{{{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( 1 \right)}}}
  \over {{{\Gamma \left( {1/2 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}}}{{{{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)}
  \over {\Gamma \left( 1 \right)}}} \over {{{\Gamma \left( {3/2 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)}}}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)} \over 1}{{\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)} \over 1}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty }
 {{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2 + m} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {3/2 + m} \right)}}
 \cr} 
$$
where
$$
x^{\,\overline {\,m} }  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {x + k}  = {{\Gamma \left( {x + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( x \right)}} 
$$
 represents the [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials);

To the gamma functions we can apply the
[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) 
to get
$$
\eqalign{
  & P =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)} \over 1}{{\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)} \over 1}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty }
 {{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2 + m} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {1 + m} \right)}
  \over {\Gamma \left( {3/2 + m} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)^{\,2} } \over 2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty }
 {{\left( {\sqrt {\,{{2\,\pi } \over {1 + m}}\,} \left( {{{1 + m} \over e}} \right)^{\,1 + m} } \right)^{\,2} }
 \over {\sqrt {\,{{2\,\pi } \over {1/2 + m}}\,} \left( {{{1/2 + m} \over e}} \right)^{\,1/2 + m} \sqrt {\,{{2\,\pi }
 \over {3/2 + m}}\,} \left( {{{3/2 + m} \over e}} \right)^{\,m + 3/2} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {\pi  \over 2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty } {{\sqrt {\left( {1/2 + m} \right)\left( {3/2 + m} \right)} }
 \over {\left( {m + 1} \right)}}{{\left( {\left( {1 + m} \right)^{\,1 + m} } \right)^{\,2} }
 \over {\left( {1/2 + m} \right)^{\,1/2 + m} \left( {3/2 + m} \right)^{\,m + 3/2} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {\pi  \over 2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty } {{\left( {1 + m} \right)^{\,2m + 1} }
 \over {\left( {1/2 + m} \right)^{\,m} \left( {3/2 + m} \right)^{\,m + 1} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {\pi  \over 2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty }
 {{\left( {1 + m} \right)m^{\,2m} } \over {\left( {3/2 + m} \right)m^{\,2m} }}{{\left( {1 + 1/m} \right)^{\,2m} }
 \over {\left( {1 + 1/\left( {2m} \right)} \right)^{\,m} \left( {1 + 1/\left( {2/3m} \right)} \right)^{\,m} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {\pi  \over 2}{{e^{\,2} } \over {e^{\,1/2} e^{\,3/2} }} = {\pi  \over 2} \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf {Hint:}$

The product can be written as

$\prod {4n^2\over 4n^2-1}$

Then you can apply $\ln$ and turn this product into a sum

Comment: This is the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) I am not sure how you make progress by turning it into a sum